# Crockford's entityify method -why the closure?

Tags: javascript

On page 90 of Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts, he has code has the following:

```
String.method('entityify', function(){

  var character = {
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '"': '&quot;'
  };

  return function(){
    return this.replace(/[<>&"]/g, function(c){
      return character[c];
    });
  };
}());

console.log("<&>".entityify());
```

Is there a good reason for the closure and immediately invoked outer function? The following seems to work just as well:

```
String.method('entityify', function(){

  var character = {
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '"': '&quot;'
  };

  return this.replace(/[<>&"]/g, function(c){
    return character[c];
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By doing it the way he did, he creates the `character` object *once* and reuses it. With your edit, you recreate it every time. You could argue it either way, but that's the difference. His uses ***fractionally*** more memory. Yours takes ***fractionally*** longer per call (maybe, depends on whether creating the object takes longer than the extra scope traversal step his has; it probably does, though). In neither case is it likely to be anything that you'd notice in the real world.

Comment: With Crockford's version, can I think of it as: because `character` is  referenced in a closure, it hangs around in memory and is not garbage collected, even once the enclosing function returns? Whereas with my version, `character` is -from my code's point of view -wiped from memory each time `entityify` returns?

Comment: @mr_c: Effectively, yes. Specifically: The function (closure) he returns via `return function(){...};` has a reference to the execution context where it was created (the context created by `method`'s call to the callback he gave it). Since the function object continues to exist after the call, the context it refers to continues to exist. That context has `character` in it, so `character` continues to exist (isn't garbage-collected). The context will survive as long as that function survives.